# set switch according to value found in firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I would like to check firebase for the current user onlineOfflineStatus which will either return "Online" or "Offline" and then so when they log in the switch is set to the right place as, as when they log out it should be set to offline meaning when the log back in it is offline, though i can't quite figure it out?

```
let switchControl: UISwitch


func setLeftNavButton() {

    var switchControl=UISwitch()
    switchControl = self.switchControl
    switchControl.isOn = true
    switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: switchControl)

}



func setSwitch(){

    let online = "Online"
    let offline = "offline"

    if currentUser?.onlineOfflineStatus == online {

        self.switchControl.isOn


    } else {

        if currentUser?.onlineOfflineStatus == offline

        self.switchControl.offline


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen connection state.

According to docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "current_user_is_connected")
  } else {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "current_user_is_connected")
  }
})
```

Update your code:

```
func setSwitch(){

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "current_user_is_connected") {
        self.switchControl.isOn = true
    } else {
        self.switchControl.isOn = false
    }
}
```